# create confirmation popup when user attempts to leave the page

Tags: javascript

Essentially I'm using this on an internal website for my company, we want to make sure that if a user is filling out a form and they accidentally click a link to a different page, they won't lose the information they've put in the form. I've tried window.onbeforeunload in javascript with no luck so i moved to jquery:

I've tried using window.onbeforeunload, which doesn't seem to have done anything. same thing in jquery with bind beforeunload:

```
    jQuery($(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        confirm('Are you sure you want to leave? Any information in "Notify" will be lost.');
    }));
```

Comment: When you have a form on the site and something is filled in, it automatically reminds the user that he has unsaved work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) properly:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">Leave</a>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. while you're here, i'm trying to get it to run only while a certain element has a certain class using this if statement: `if (jQuery('#notify-tab').hasClass('ui-tabs-tab')) { (your code above) } else {console.log('false')}` but it is always returning flase, i don't think there are any syntax errors & I've checked the element using inspect & it has the class & id I've specified above.

Comment: @TrentonMoore I couldn't say without seeing all the relevant code (HTML and CSS) and that really is a different question than what you've posted here. Please mark this as "the" answer and post a new question about the `if/then`.